# hashtable not working because of scanf()

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, scanf, hashtable

I'm learning C data structures. I've the following code, which is resulting in a segmentation fault.
I've used the hash function from K&R C (2nd Ed.).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define HASHSIZE 101

typedef struct Details
{
    char *name;
    float checkTotal;
    float tipTotal;
    int numReciepts;
    struct Details *next;
    struct Details *prev;
} det;

static det *hashtab[HASHSIZE];

char *str_dup(char *);
det *lookup(char *);
det *insert(char *, float, float);
unsigned hash(char *);
void printData(char *);
int main()
{
    printf("1. Enter details.\n");
    printf("2. Print List of employees.\n");
    char *s;
    float cT; //checkTotal
    float tT; //tipTotal
    while (1)
    {
        int command = 0;
        printf("Enter option: ");
        scanf("%d", &command);
        if (command == 1)
        {
            printf("Enter name: ");
            scanf("%s", s);
            printf("Enter check total: ");
            scanf("%f", &cT);
            printf("Enter tip total: ");
            scanf("%f", &tT);
            insert(s, cT, tT);
        }
        else if (command == 2)
        {
            char *p;
            printf("Enter name of employee: ");
            scanf("%s", p); //including this line causes seg fault.
            printData(p);
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned hash(char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;
    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; *s++)
        hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}
det *lookup(char *name)
{
    det *ptr;
    for (ptr = hashtab[hash(name)]; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, ptr->name) == 0)
            return ptr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

det *insert(char *name, float cT, float tT)
{
    det *new;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((new = lookup(name)) == NULL)
    {
        new = (det *)malloc(sizeof(new));
        if (new == NULL || (new->name = str_dup(name)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        new->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = new;
        new->checkTotal += cT;
        new->tipTotal += tT;
        new->numReciepts++;
        printf("Details of '%s' inserted.\n", name);
    }
    else
    {
        new->checkTotal += cT;
        new->tipTotal += tT;
        new->numReciepts++;
        printf("Details of '%s' updated.\n", name);
    }
}
char *str_dup(char *s)
{
    char *p;
    p = (char *)malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}

void printData(char *p)
{
    det *ptr;
    if ((ptr = lookup(p)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Emplyee Name  : %s\n", ptr->name);
        printf("Total amount  : %6.2f\n", ptr->checkTotal);
        printf("Total tip     : %6.2f\n", ptr->tipTotal);
        printf("Total reciepts: %6.2d\n", ptr->numReciepts);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Employee '%s' does not exist.\n", p);
        return;
    }
}
```

Without the inclusion of **scanf()** in **else if:main**, every thing works fine. Calling **printData()** with a hard coded string also works.

Inclusion of **scanf()** in **else if:main** results in **segmentation fault** after prompting for name.

I have tried and can not think of the reason. As far as I know:

1. my code in **if:main** is not accessing anything in **else if:main**.
2. **if** should not break because of something wrong in **else if** even if it is wrong. (at least in this scenario, or as far as my understanding goes)

Thanks and any tips for future from experts are appreciated!

P.S: **scanf():if** is working perfectly.

Comment: You didn't allocate any memory for `p` to point to.

Comment: You have the same problem with the `s` pointer. Using uninitialized pointers results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I've tried passing an array.

Comment: Using arrays should work. You should make sure that the `scanf()` doesn't try to read a name longer than can fit in the array.

Comment: compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: @Barmar Using arrays for both s and p worked. Thank you very much. BTW, what should I initialize s/p to if I want to use them as pointers?

Comment: You should use `malloc()` to allocate memory for them.

Comment: Read also the documentation of every function used e.g. [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot gentlemen!

Comment: also, `-fsanitize=undefined` to GCC.

Comment: The variable `p` in the "else" is uninitilalised.  Passing it to ANY function therefore gives undefined behaviour.   However, that's not the only part of your code which gives undefined behaviour.  `s` in `main()` is also uninitialised before passing it to `scanf()` - if that works, you're just getting lucky.

Comment: `new = (det *)malloc(sizeof(new));` -->> `new = malloc(sizeof *new);`